# Forcing browsers to reload cached Flash files

Tags: flash

How? I know I can append a random number as part of a query string when embedding, but what if the Flash file itself loads another Flash file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:** you can't.

**Long answer:** If this file loads additional data using a specific class/framework you could replace this class by your own simply by creating a class with the same name in your swf. The one which loads the one which loads all other stuff. The modified class will be used instead the one in the loadedd SWF.

But if simple Loader API is used everything gets trickier. You'll have to parse loaded swf and modify Loader.load calls. There's a good [library](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-bytecode/introduction.html) By Claus Wahlers which can do that.